# What things should I consider about Titan while landing, in terms of geography?

Tags: space-travel, spaceships, space-colonization

What are the challenges to landing on Saturn's moon, Titan, with respect to atmosphere and geography?

Consider we are landing a team of scientists, in a ship based geometrically on the Jupiter of *Lost in Space* (1998). On Earth we have higher gravity to deal with, and entry friction in our atmosphere. But we have stable ground to support landing feet, or soft water-landing options without them. I think a craft designed to land on Titan must be designed with a different atmosphere and geography in mind. Can I know a few key considerations to landing there, posed by Titan's geography and atmosphere?

[image]

*(Jupiter 2)*

Comment: Hi Pranay, welcome to Worldbuilding! There are a few problems here: you're asking multiple questions while you should focus on one, you're giving us an example of a spaceship but, if you want us to consider it, it is better to include the relevant information of that ship in your question. Next: what is the reason you ask it here instead of on [Space Exploration](https://space.stackexchange.com/) (not that I'm saying that it would be a good fit there)? And why the peculiar capitalization?

Comment: In addition to what @Joachim said, this question is open-ended and broad. Our [help/dont-ask] states, "To prevent your question from being flagged and possibly removed, avoid asking subjective questions where … you are asking an open-ended, hypothetical question." We could list all kinds if issues, but they would be based on assumptions concerning not just the shape of your craft, but the materials used, its propulsion, it's landing design and procedures... Consequently, this Q might be closed for needing details or clarity. Please take our [tour] and read our [help] to learn more. Thanks!

Comment: And before you suggest that you've solved all those problems by telling us it's the Jupiter from *Lost in Space,* please understand that there are at least three such ships, one from the 1965 TV series, one from the 1998 movie, and a third from the 2018 TV series... none of which are identical to any other and none of them have substantial specifications that would allow us to evaluate how well they'd land on Titan. (This question might actually be better suited to asking on [scifi.se] where it can be judged based on in-world canon.)

Comment: The question could be narrowed down to "what is the biggest difficulty of surviving on Titan"

Comment: All these worlds are yours except Titan. Attempt no landings there.

Comment: I've changed the title, by copying the question that is stated in the opening text. It is far more specific. @Pranay if you don't like the edit, please undo it. Take into account there are close votes.. better specify your question further ! We can't write your story for you..

Comment: What form of propulsion does your ship have? "... a ship based geometrically on the Jupiter of Lost in Space (1998)" does not tell us that.

Answer (score 1):

### Getting to solid ground

Probably the main thing you would have to consider is the extreme temperatures that appear on the moon (as low as -180 Celsius), this makes it very hard to even approach landing as an atmosphere this cold will quickly leech out the heat out of your ship and make it unusable, likely turn everyone on board into ice statues sooner or later. In order to stop that from happening, the ship would need to be completely covered with some sort of insulation layer, one stronger than any we currently have access to.

Even harder still is **actually getting the researchers out**, the suits would have to be crazy durable and complex in order to maintain a liveable temperature inside, we don't have the means and likely will not for an extremely long time to make something like them.

Another point here is the *literal* getting out part, conventional airlocks have worked very well for us thus far because most of the things we've been flying to don't have a proper atmosphere, but the atmosphere isn't the issue here, the temperature *very* is. The ship would need to have pipes insulated with the same material coating it in order to pump out the gas from the airlock without internally damaging itself. The actual airtight door would also need to be insulated... and even then, some heat would still escape every time the team needs to leave or return, which is bad, because heating equals resources, resources equals more load, more load equals more fuel and so on.

The only advantage Titan offers in terms of its atmosphere is the density (and its low gravity), this makes it exceptionally easy to launch your ship with little fuel, use plane-like devices for transport, and build large structures. (all of which is mostly impossible due to the temperature but oh well)

### Landing

When it comes to geography, it largely depends on *where* you want to land it, similar to how you wouldn't just build a ship that can adapt to the geography of "earth" because of how many different types of terrain our planet has.

But it would be entirely possible to find a flat enough area on the surface to land, as the landing itself isn't the problem here, the "everything else is".

That being said, the moon's surface is kind of a mystery as we don't fully know what said surface is even made of (it's probably just ice and bits of hydrocarbons, but we don't know for sure). It may resemble a desert made of tiny frozen shards of natural gas, it may be more "rocky" with a jagged layer of ice, we don't fully know, so this one is a bit harder.

Comment: Keeping a ship warm is simple, What's complicated is venting heat off of a spaceship, especially while in space.

Comment: @SurpriseDog in the vacuum of space yes, but Titan has an atmosphere that can conduct and convect heat orders of magnitude more efficiently. So we need some way to vent heat on the way their, and then efficiently shut that down when we land

Comment: Some quick math suggests that a 10m diameter sphere would require 2MW to keep it's external skin temperature at 25 degrees. That is assuming no insulation. Even modest household-wall insulation (R=13) drops that to a much more manageable 6KW (if my math is right). I don't think this is as much of a problem as you think. Yes, you need mass for insulation but it's 'just' an engineering problem